# Adding an onclick function to go to url Code

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am using this code to get URL from "button_url" and I need `onclick` function will act as a link go to a URL.

I want to place this button in several places on the same page.
The problem is that it only works at one place. How to solve it?

```
<? php $ button_url = get_field ('button_url'); ?>
<script>
jQuery (document) .ready (function ($) {
var button_url = '<? php echo $ button_url; ?> ';
$ ("# myBtn"). attr ("href", button_url);
});
</script>
```

The code

```
<a href="" id="myBtn"> button </a>
```

Comment: If you have several placed you need to use a class. An id must be unique on the page. Change $ ("#myBtn") to $ (".myBtn"). On the html page change the id to class <a href="" class="myBtn"> button </a>

Comment: I tried, it didn't work.

Comment: Why would you use JavaScript for this to begin with? Why don’t you just put the value of `$button_url` as the content of the `href` attribute of that link in the HTML output?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to have multiple element with same ID(#myBtn), which is not valid(https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp). So if you change it to class(.myBtn) instead it should work.

```
<? php $ button_url = get_field ('button_url'); ?>
<script>
jQuery (document) .ready (function ($) {
var button_url = '<? php echo $ button_url; ?> ';
$ (".myBtn"). attr ("href", button_url);
});
</script>

<a href="" class="myBtn"> button </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<a href="link1" class="myBtn">button</a>
<a href="link2" class="myBtn">button</a>
<script>
$("body").on("click", ".myBtn", function(){
window.location = $(this).attr("href");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple a tags, here it s an example how to put a link to a to all your a tags. You need to use class, not id. An id it s unique on the page

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var button_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'; //your link from php
$ (".myBtn").attr("href", button_url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">

<a href="" class="myBtn"> button 1 </a><br/>
<a href="" class="myBtn"> button 2 </a><br/>
<a href="" class="myBtn"> button 3 </a><br/>
<a href="" class="myBtn"> button 4 </a><br/>
<a href="" class="myBtn"> button 5 </a><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
$("#myBtn").attr("href", button_url);
```

to

```
$("a#myBtn").attr("href", button_url);
```